# An Array of Function Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to figure out on how can I make an array of pointers to functions that are inside a class. Where an element in an array represents a unique function.

Tiles.h code:

```
class tiles: public box
{
    public:
        void north2east(float trans_x, float trans_y);
        void north2west(float trans_x, float trans_y);
        void south2east(float trans_x, float trans_y);
        void south2west(float trans_x, float trans_y);
};
```

Tiles.cpp code:

```
void tiles::north2east(float trans_x, float trans_y); { }
void tiles::north2west(float trans_x, float trans_y); { }
void tiles::south2east(float trans_x, float trans_y); { }
void tiles::south2west(float trans_x, float trans_y); { }
```

I've heard that you can do it by adding the following in the Tiles.cpp file:

```
typedef void (*FUNC_ARRAY) (float trans_x, float trans_y);
FUNC_ARRAY functions[] = {
    tiles::north2east,
    tiles::north2west,
    tiles::south2east,
    tiles::south2west
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

> a value of type "void (tiles::*)(float trans_x, float trans_y)" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "FUNC_ARRAY"

Tips and suggestions on solving the code are welcome!

Comment: That typedef can only be used for ordinary functions or static member functions.

Comment: See http://www.warplife.com/tips/code/c++/member-pointers.html for how to declare pointers to member functions.

Comment: You assign pointer to methods and those aren't pointers to functions as you cannot invoke them without an object instance.

Answer (score 5):

Just change your `typedef` to:

```
typedef void (tiles::*FUNC_ARRAY) (float trans_x, float trans_y);
//            ^^^^^^^
```

Your current typedef can only be used for regular functions and static member functions. What you need there is a pointer to a member function.

Comment: @VesmirPendel have in mind that now you will be able to invoke those method only on objects, like: `tiles t; (t.*function[1])(1.0, 1.0);` or `tiles *t = new t; (t->*function[1])(1.0, 1.0);`